# F# solution without mutation

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, c#-to-f#, mutation

Just for fun I read [these](https://www.toptal.com/c-sharp/interview-questions) interview questions and tried to find the solutions in both C# and F# and I struggle to do following in idiomatic F# without mutating a boolean value or using a regex:

***You’re given a word string containing one or many $ symbols, e.g.:
"foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ "
Question: How do you remove the second and third occurrences of $ from a given string?***

My imperative F# solution with mutation:

```
let input = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ "
let sb = new StringBuilder()
let mutable first = true

let f c=
    if c='$' && first then first<-false
    else sb.Append(c) |> ignore

input |> Seq.iter f
```

(And a C# one):

```
var input = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ ";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
bool first = true;
input.ForEach(c => {
    switch (c)
    {
        case '$' when first: first = false; break;
        default: sb.Append(c);break;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let f (s:string) =
    s.Split('$')
    |> Array.toList
    |> function
        | [] -> ""
        | [ a ] -> a
        | [ a; b ] -> a + "$" + b
        | a :: b :: c :: rest -> a + "$" + b + c + (rest |> String.concat "$")

f "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ "
// "foo bar foo $ bar  foo bar  "

f "1 $ 2 $ 3 $ 4 $ 5 $"
//"1 $ 2  3  4 $ 5 $"
```

Note that this solution only removes the second and third instance of `$`. If you want to remove all except the first one then replace `String.concat "$"` with `String.concat ""`

Comment: That's correct! I was playing around with matching but couldn't get it done. Your solution actually made me realize, I read the question wrong and was removing the first instead of the others, so thank you also for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
let f (s:string) =
    s.Split('$')
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i t -> (if i > 3 || i = 1 then "$" else "") + t)
    |> String.concat ""
```

and here is another one that scans every `char` using <s>tail</s> recursion and `seq` computational expression:

```
let f (s:string) =
    let rec chars n input = seq {
        match Seq.tryHead input with
        | Some '$' ->   if not(n = 1 || n = 2) then yield  '$'
                        yield! Seq.tail input |> chars (n+1)
        | Some c   ->   yield  c
                        yield! Seq.tail input |> chars n
        | None     ->   ()
    }
    chars 0 s
    |> fun cs -> new string(Seq.toArray cs)
```

It may be longer <s>but is probably more efficient than the first one</s>.

**Edit:** Nope, it is not more efficient and it is not a tail recursion, probably because it happens inside a Computation Expression.

Comment: Your second solution is actually multiple orders of magnitude slower when using the original example input. It seems to do a lot more allocation because there are so many `seq`/`IEnumerable` objects created. I would generally try to avoid mixing recursion and `seq` for both readability and performance.

Comment: You are right. In fact it doesn't even consider it a tail recursion, probably because it is a computation expression. Thank you!